# Lingui: Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {id})

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, linguijs

According to [the documentation](https://lingui.js.org/ref/macro.html#jsmacro-t) we can use `t` macro instead of `i18n._()` call. An example of corresponding macro transformation:

```js
import { t } from "@lingui/macro"
const message = t`Hello World`

// ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓

import { i18n } from "@lingui/core"
const message = i18n._(/*i18n*/{
  id: 'Hello World',
})
```

And so I should be able to write:

```jsx
  <TextField label={t`Login`}/>
```

where **TextField** is a Material UI component.

But that doesn't work. Instead I get a runtime error:

> Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys
> {id}).

as if `t` was converted to the object

```js
{
  id: 'Login',
}
```

and not the `i18n._(...)` function call.

I couldn't find any information about this here or among [project's pages](https://github.com/lingui/js-lingui).

Comment: I tried and it worked for me. Link: https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-liskov-xmghg?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Thanks Swaraj. In my case there were few differences. First, I had i18n injected via withi18n. Then I used some outdated version and third - I initialized I18nProvider differently. See my own reply below please.

Answer (score 0):

Answering to myself.

It's hard to tell the actual reason, but after I updated the code according to a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/nextjs-lingui-forked-u7qpt?file=/pages/index.tsx) kindly provided by Sergio Moreno, it now works.

Basically `I18nProvider` should have been initialized differently. Specifically:

Was:

```jsx
<I18nProvider language={language} catalogs={i18nCatalogs}>
```

Becomes:

```jsx
<I18nProvider i18n={i18n}>
```

See the issue for more details: https://github.com/lingui/js-lingui/issues/946